# Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, okta, okta-api, spring-boot-starter-security

I am new to Spring Security. I am using okta OIDC application to secure my Resource Server.

I have the following application.yml

```
okta:
  oauth2:
    client-id: {client-id}
    issuer: https://{okta-domain}.okta.com
```

I have the following security configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("user_pwd").roles("USER").and()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin_pwd").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error after adding the above piece of code:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:483) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:311) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.symbiose.OAuthResourceServerApplication.main(OAuthResourceServerApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't configure anyRequest after itself
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.anyRequest(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:74) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.configure(ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter.java:30) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration.configure(ResourceServerConfiguration.java:154) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:231) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:322) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:94) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4941180f.init(<generated>) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104) ~[spring-security-config-5.3.4.RELEASE.jar:5.3.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Also, how do I validate the user and password dynamically without hard coding the values as above in the "InMemoryAuthentication". For ex: I have created few people and added them in User and Admin groups as per my requirement in Okta, added the user and admin groups to my OIDC SPA App.

In that case, the users with specific user or admin role will be logging in which I need to capture and restrict access to few APIs in case of user ROLE. How do I configure the above code to dynamically verify the logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few questions in here, so I'll attempt to answer them.

First, you are configuring both Basic Auth and an OAuth resource server.

My suggestion is to keep it simple and JUST use OAuth.  You *can* configure them both, but you will need to explicitly do so in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

i.e. in `configure()` add:

```java
// require authentication for ALL endpoints
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

// enable resource server to process JWTs
http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
```

One issue you have is you have this line:

```java
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
```

This allows ALL unauthenticated requests.

If you do NOT define a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` at all, the default is the first code block I posted.

I usually recommend to start with the defaults. The default is a secure application :)

Once you have that working, you can add a custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`. but start with a similar default configuration.

Next, start allowing any unauthenticated paths, something like:

```java
http.authorizeRequests()
    // Allow anon access to the root application
    .antMatchers("/", "/index.html").permitAll()

    // Require authentication for ALL other requests
    .anyRequest().authenticated();

// enable resource server, process JWTs
http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
```

Finally, add other authentication sources (in your case basic auth if needed).
For role-based security you have a couple of options too, you can either add them via annotations or in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

This post should walk you through everything in a bit more detail: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/06/20/spring-preauthorize